# firebase's console in Realtime Database section wont stop loading?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

Today I accidently delete my project but I recovered right away, anything in the app working fine. But when I enter the real-time database section on the firebase web console, it keeps loading forever. Any help for this problem?
[image]

Thank u in advance

Comment: Edit: And I also let a friend to join in my project, but he said that he didnt do anything related to the database yet

Comment: Troubleshooting steps: 1) Check the JavaScript console of your browser for errors. 2) Disable any browser extensions (such as Ad blockers) you may have running. 3) Try with a different browser. 4) Try on another network, to determine whether your network or ISP is blocking the traffic/

Answer (score 2):

The troubleshooting steps for this type of problem:

1. Check the JavaScript console of your browser for errors.
2. Disable any browser extensions (such as Ad blockers) you may have running.
3. Try with a different browser.
4. Try on another network, to determine whether your network or ISP is blocking the traffic.

Comment: In my case pc date was 15days back